# Loop through .json files during python script

Tags: python, json

first time here and I am fairly inexperienced so sorry if I miss interpret anything :)

I have a script that can create an account on a website, its gets the user credential from a config.json file. The only issue is it can only create 1 account per run. Is there anyway to set this scrip up to run multiple user credential that would be enclosed in the config.json file?

PY Code Below:

```
import json
import requests

s = requests.Session()

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-API-Key': '--xxx--',
    'Accept': '*',
    'X-Debug': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'FootPatrol/2.0 CFNetwork/808.2.16 Darwin/16.3.0',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'MESH-Commcerce-Channel': 'iphone-app'
}

with open("config.json") as jsons:
    config = json.load(jsons)

req = s.post("https://commerce.mesh.mx/stores/footpatrol/customers", 
headers=headers, json=config)
print(req.text)
```

config.json below:

```
            {
            "phone": "07901893000",
            "password": "passwprd3213",
            "firstName": "Jon",
            "gender": "",
            "addresses": [
            {
            "locale": "gb",
            "country": "United Kingdom",
            "address1": "54 yellow Road",
            "town": "Oxford",
            "postcode": "OX1 1SW",
            "isPrimaryBillingAddress": true,
            "isPrimaryAddress": true
            }
            ],
            "title": "",
            "email": "fdgsgfdg@gmail.com",
            "isGuest": false,
            "lastName": "Thomas"
            },
```

Many thanks :)

Comment: you might want to remove your API key and generate a new one.

Comment: Hi, the API key always stays the same. I am trying to create say 200 accounts in one go, the problem I have is at the moment I can only create 1 at a time.

Comment: Yes but posting your API key here allows anybody that sees YOUR key to use it to do possibly bad things with it in YOUR name. ;)

Comment: The API key shouldn't be shared because it could be sensitive information. If you're paying for requests, someone could take the key and make their own requests from your account.

Comment: Oh my misunderstanding - thank you!

Comment: Just to be safe, revoke credentials for the one you posted and create a new one for you.

Comment: If your data is stored in a json array in your file, then `json.load` should return a list of dicts containing your credentials data, over which you can iterate. So, it depends on the exact data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to set up the script to run for multiple users.

First let us start with organising the `config.json` file which will contain the configuration for all of the users. The file will be a JSON array which will contain the JSON objects. Here is an example of the file structure:

```
[
    {
        "phone": "07901893000",
        "password": "passwprd3213",
        "firstName": "Jon",
        "gender": "",
        "addresses": [
        {
        "locale": "gb",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "address1": "54 yellow Road",
        "town": "Oxford",
        "postcode": "OX1 1SW",
        "isPrimaryBillingAddress": true,
        "isPrimaryAddress": true
        }
        ],
        "title": "",
        "email": "fdgsgfdg@gmail.com",
        "isGuest": false,
        "lastName": "Thomas"
    },
    {
        "phone": "07901893000",
        "password": "passwprd3213",
        "firstName": "Mickey",
        "gender": "",
        "addresses": [
        {
        "locale": "gb",
        "country": "USA",
        "address1": "123 USA Road",
        "town": "New Oxford",
        "postcode": "OX1 1SW",
        "isPrimaryBillingAddress": true,
        "isPrimaryAddress": true
        }
        ],
        "title": "",
        "email": "fdgsgfdg@gmail.com",
        "isGuest": false,
        "lastName": "Thomas"
    }
]
```

Now, lets change the code:

```
import json
import requests

s = requests.Session()

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-API-Key': '--xxx--',
    'Accept': '*',
    'X-Debug': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'FootPatrol/2.0 CFNetwork/808.2.16 Darwin/16.3.0',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'MESH-Commcerce-Channel': 'iphone-app'
}

with open("config.json") as jsons:
    configs = json.load(jsons)

    for config in configs:
        req = s.post("https://commerce.mesh.mx/stores/footpatrol/customers", 
        headers=headers, json=config)
        print(req.text)
```

The line `configs = json.load(jsons)` will return a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary will be a config for particular. You need to iterate through the list. After that the code is same for making a request for a given config (config for a user).

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are amazing thank you - works like a dream! First time using stack and cannot believe the generosity here (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just put everything starting at `with` inside a loop that goes across all of the files you've told it to look for.

```
files = ["config_1.json", "config_2.json", "config_3.json"]

for file in files:
  with open(file) as jsons:
    config = json.load(jsons)

  req = s.post("https://commerce.mesh.mx/stores/footpatrol/customers", 
  headers=headers, json=config)
  print(req.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful! Is there anyway to have all the details in on config file? Will take a long time to create sat 200 files with unique details.

Comment: Of course there's a way. However, the title of the question asks how to "loop through .json files", so that's the question I answered. The people here like to be very structured about the question-and-answer format. I also feel like you have the tools (given what I've posted and your existing Python knowledge) to load your JSON file into a list of dicts and then have the `for` loop pull out each dict to send to the request.